# Открыть панораму Google во всплывающем окне

Tags: jquery, google-maps, iframe

Есть панорама созданная на гугл картах https://goo.gl/maps/K8KvJ я пытаюсь открыть её на сайте во всплывающем окне плагина Jquery ColorBox. В ответ получаю ошибку

> *Refused to display 'в кавычках URL карты' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.*

На сколько я понял нужно передать какой-то дополнительный заголовок чтобы открыть карту таким образом (пост с похожей проблемой на StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options ). Но как это сделать открывая страницу в Jquery ColorBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Настройки [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) запрещают отображение страницы во `iframe` на страницах стороннего домена. Это регулируется заголовками сервера, который отдает карты.

Такое решение принимается в целях безопасности или защиты от нецелевого использования контента на сайте.

**Решение в использовании функции [Google Maps API Street View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-embed)** (вам потребуется ключ разработчика, количество показов будет ограниченно в зависимости от статуса разработчика).